# Java - List Error in Code

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an error in my code.

I have these two lists:

```
public static final List<Class<? extends Packet>> OUT_PACKETS = Arrays.asList(PacketPing.class);
public static final List<Class<? extends Packet>> IN_PACKETS = Arrays.asList(PacketPing.class);
```

But if I try to add the PacketPing class to this list, it gets marked red. But why?

Here is my Packet.class:

```
public interface Packet {

public void read(ByteBuf byteBuf) throws IOException;
public void write(ByteBuf byteBuf) throws IOException;
}
```

And this is my PacketPing.class:

```
public class PacketPing implements Packet {

private long time;

public PacketPing(){ }
public PacketPing(long time){  this.time = time; }

@Override
public void read(ByteBuf byteBuf) throws IOException {
    this.time = byteBuf.readLong();
}

@Override
public void write(ByteBuf byteBuf) throws IOException {
    byteBuf.writeLong(this.time);
}

public long getTime() { return time; }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
This is what my IDE says, but nothing from that works...
[Link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW6Uz.png)

And I use Java 8

Comment: Can you also write the error that are you getting?

Comment: Are you importing the PacketPing class?

Comment: Compiles fine for me. Please provide your compiler error.

Comment: Usually, when an IDE "marks red", it also display an explanation for the "red", usually while hovering the underlined text with the mouse cursor. That is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @daniu It doesnt compile. Error message `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Class<PacketPing>> to List<Class<? extends 
  Packet>>`

Comment: @Jens I'm looking at the code I copied into my Eclipse right now, and it compiles fine. Maybe it's the Eclipse compiler that allows it?

Comment: @daniu I copied it into eclipse too. I get the error message. Maybe a quetion of Java version? I tried it with Java7

Comment: @daniu I have tried it with Java 8 and it works fine there. See my answer

Comment: @Jens Ah, that explains it. Upvoted for finding out before me :)

Comment: I edited my question with a link to the error which IntelliJ gives me.
And the version of Java I use is Java 8

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this specific way  if you use java7:

```
public static final List<Class<? extends Packet>> OUT_PACKETS = Arrays.<Class<? extends Packet>>asList(PacketPing.class);
```

In java8 your declaration is correct and will be compiled fine

Comment: @zettee in my Environment this works. Atleast it is compileable. Which Java Version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Java 8

Comment: @zettee you are sure? in my Environment it compiles fine with Java8

Comment: I'll try it in eclipse now. I will see if it works there